Creating Helper function is not working in codeigniter 4
in autoload.php
 public $helpers = [
        'general'
    ];

helper is loaded and helper file defined 2 functions
<?php

function datetimeformat($date)
{
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
}

function randomnumber()
{
    return "111";
} 

and in controller  i called the helper but is not working
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;


/**
 * Rating Controller For Admin
 */
class Rating extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        // Load either general_helper or general
        if ( helper('general_helper') || helper('general')) {
echo "test";exit();
        }

    }
}

in this code helper is not loaded i cant find what is the issue please any one have idea

Are you facing any error message?  What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Does this answer your question? How to autoload helper functions in codeigniter 4

This line is useless if ( helper('general_helper') || helper('general'))
You do not have to check whether the helper has been loaded.
It should be loaded, since you did it within the autoload.
If it's not loaded, then:

Verify that the name of the helper general_helper corresponds to the name of the file. It must be \Helpers\general_helper.php

Call public $helpers = ['general_helper']; in the autoload.


This is for CI4, as described in the official documentation.

The helper() function does not return a value, so don’t try to assign it to a variable.
So your conditional check will never evaluate as true.
After you've loaded your helpers, just check if the desired function exists using exit(function_exists('randomnumber') ? 'exists' : 'nope');.
See also:

How to list all loaded libraries and helpers in a CodeIgniter application?
What is the correct way to check if library/helper/core files are loaded in CodeIgniter

